# Remove assets when bundling cordova app

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, meteor

We have a Meteor application with some large image files for a slider.

We show the images on the desktop app, but want to exclude the images in the mobile apps because they are not necessary in the mobile app and are downloaded every time a new version is published.

Is there any way to exclude files e.g. in the public folder when bundling the cordova app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the IMHO best solution to this problem is to put the images into a package that uses the addFiles function to include the images only in the desktop application.

Here's a link to the Cordova specific API you could use:
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Meteor-Cordova-integration

Answer (score 0):

Files in the public folder are not automatically sent to the client unless requested by some template or javascript. In my app for example I send lower resolution images if I detect a mobile device. The folder has images in multiple resolutions but only the *right one* is sent.

Comment: Thank you. I'll give it a try!